# Safari - CSS Transition does not fire during onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, safari, css-transitions

I'm trying to implement page transitions using onbeforeunload by adding/removing a class from my code to trigger a CSS animation.

It works in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Safari. I see that the "page-animate-hidden" class is being added to the DOM in Safari properly when it hits the onbeforeunload event, but the transition does not visually render.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

SCSS

```
.page-animate {
    clip-path: circle(100%);
    max-height: 999999em;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0s .6s, overflow 0s .6s, clip-path .6s;

    &.page-animate-hidden {
    clip-path: circle(0%);
    max-height: 101vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0s, overflow 0s, clip-path .6s;
    }
}
```

JS

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
    if (!NM.ignoreOnBeforeUnload){
        $('.page-animate').addClass('page-animate-hidden');
    }
    NM.ignoreOnBeforeUnload = false;
});
```

I've tried different unload events, but that doesn't seem to be the issue since beforeunload is causing the class to be added. It seems to be a Safari-only rendering issue.